# Angular dynamic component loader ng0100

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, loading

Angular 12:

I'm trying to insert a variable array of components.
with a similar code to the one on the guid:

html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let buttons of buttonArray">
        <ng-template appHeaderComponent></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

ts

```
@Input('buttons')
buttonArray: Array<HeaderSubComponentHolder>;

@ViewChildren(HeaderComponentDirective)
headerComponents: QueryList<any>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.loadButtons();
}

loadButtons() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.headerComponents.length; i++) {
      const headComponent = this.headerComponents.get(i);
      const button: HeaderSubComponentHolder = this.buttonArray[i];
      const viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef = headComponent.viewContainerRef;
      const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        button.type
      );
      viewContainerRef.clear();
      const componentRef =
        viewContainerRef.createComponent<HeaderSubComponent>(factory);
      componentRef.instance.data = button.data;
    }
  }
```

But i'm getting an NG0100 error, the first time accessing the page, the buttons appear as normal.
But if i go back with a back arrow, the buttons don't appear (I get an undefined error in "this.headerComponents")

Any tip about how to deal with this?

**EDIT:** Think i found the solution, if i understood the problem is that the sub component bindings were changed during the "After view init" cycle of the component that contains them.
I added this at the end

```
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: thanks alejandro, your solution helped me